# Search multiple words at a time in a row in Mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner in Mysql Php. I want to make a search box which can find a row containing searching multiple words of a table in mysql. I have got a script via internet which is given below. When i type multiple words it show the row which have minimum a searching word. But I want that it will only show the row which have searching multiple words. Please Help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV='Content-Type' CONTENT='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>
<title>Page title</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border: solid 1px black;
}
td {
padding: 2px 6px;
border: solid 1px black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post'>
<p>Search for: <input type='text' name='search' size='20'
maxlength='64'></p>
<p><input type='submit' value='Search'></p>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
$connx = mysql_connect('localhost', '*****', '*****') or
die("connx");
$db = mysql_select_db('test') or die(mysql_error());
# convert to upper case, trim it, and replace spaces with "|":
$search = (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')) ?
stripslashes($_POST['search']) :
$_POST['search'];
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);
$search = strtoupper(preg_replace('/\s+/', '|',
trim($_POST['search'])));
# create a MySQL REGEXP for the search:
$regexp = "REGEXP '[[:<:]]($search)[[:>:]]'";
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE UPPER(`description`) $regexp
OR ".
"`name` $regexp";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die($query . " - " .
mysql_error());
echo "<table>\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
foreach($row as $key => $value)
{
echo "<td>$value</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just a sidenote, `mysql_` [will become obsolete](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Alternatives are `mysqli` and `PDO`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
$search = explode(" ", $_POST['search']);
$description = "";
$name = "";
foreach($search AS $s)
{
    $description .= "`description` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($s)."%' AND ";
    $name .= "`name` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($s)."%' AND ";
}

$description = substr($description, 0, -4);
$name = substr($name, 0, -4);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ($description) OR ($name)";
```

If your search term was something like "Doctor John" your query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`description` LIKE '%Doctor%' AND `description` LIKE '%John%') OR (`name` LIKE '%Doctor%' AND `name` LIKE '%John%')
```

which obviously makes BOTH words a requirement in either the description or name field.
Is this like what you were looking for?

PS - look into the [PDO library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for PHP. mysql_ functions are too old to be considered standard anymore. They will work, but you should upgrade.

Comment: When i click search button with blank search box it show the entire columns totally. How to avoid it?

Comment: put the entire search processing in an if statement... if(trim($_POST['search']) != ''){ ... }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to say, but here what I think you want:

```
$words = explode(" ", $_POST["search"]);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ";
$where = array();
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $where[] = "UPPER(`description`) LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($word)."%'";
}
$sql .= implode(" OR ", $where);
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Nice post. I have just changed $sql .= implode("AND", $where);