# MYSQLi Query Issue (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I am writing a php script that takes in a search form separated by spaces (example: 'purple mustang') and I would like to search a table in my database, let's call it `articles`.

Articles has 2 fields, `title` and `tags`. The `title` is something simple like "purple mustang for sale" and the `tags` are a comma separated string like "purple, car, mustang, sale, new"

I would like to pull out the information of the database by matching the searched terms to both the `title` and the comma separated `tags`, but prioritizing matches to the `title` to come before matches to `tags`. (I hope that makes sense)

So with this example, I want to pull out anything that matches the terms purple mustang in the `title`, and then below that (for anything not matching in the title) anything matching the `tags`.

Right now I am doing a simple `SELECT` from the table `articles` but I'm not sure how to go about using the LIKE to search multiple keywords, like 'purple mustang'.

Any help here would be appreciated. I have used lots of MYSQL before but never tried to match multiple keywords to multiple fields before.

Comment: So what have you tried so far, show us.

Comment: Did you Google `search multiple words mysql`? Cuz I found a whole slew of results. [**Here's one**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327108/mysql-php-searching-for-multiple-words)

Comment: This post looks like exactly what I need.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118838/search-multiple-words-at-a-time-in-a-row-in-mysql-php

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE
title LIKE '%mustang%'
AND
title LIKE '%purple%'
```